# Get Default Export in JavaScriptCore

Tags: javascript, c, jslint, javascriptcore

Goal: I'm trying to run JSLint in JavaScriptCore.

## Old Version

Older JSLint releases exposed a global function named `JSLINT` like this:

```
var JSLINT = (function () {
    ...
}
```

This was easy to retrieve and execute in JavaScriptCore:

```
// Assume 'ctx' is a JSGlobalContextRef
// Assume we have already called JSEvaluateScript()

JSStringRef jsFunctionName = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("JSLINT");
JSValueRef jsLintFunctionValue = JSObjectGetProperty(ctx, JSContextGetGlobalObject(ctx), jsFunctionName, NULL);
JSStringRelease(jsFunctionName);
    
JSObjectRef jsLintFunction = JSValueToObject(ctx, jsLintFunctionValue, &exception);
```

With that reference, I could then use `JSObjectCallAsFunction()` to execute the function. Worked perfectly.

## New Version

Now, JSLint has moved to this:

```
export default Object.freeze(function jslint(
    source = "",
    option_object = empty(),
    global_array = []
) { 
    ... 
});
```

The documentation for JavaScriptCore is poor. I have tried many things but am clearly missing something obvious. How can I retrieve and execute the `jslint` function now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick version

If @kaizhu's answer didn't give you want you wanted, another option to get to a state closer to what you had before is to...

1. Comment out two lines of export code [that starts on this line](https://github.com/jslint-org/jslint/blob/5cfd439eb7a7251cecd42d4b506b2eae61c6b4ce/jslint.mjs#L8202).
2. Reference lower-case `jslint`

Here are the two lines you need to comment out with today's version of JSLint.

```
// export default Object.freeze(jslint_export);
// jslint_import_meta_url = import.meta.url;
```

If you include that now-edited file in a project, the function `jslint` is in your global scope.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(jslint("var a = 5").warnings, null, "  "))
```

Results:

```
[
  {
    "a": ";",
    "b": "(end)",
    "code": "expected_a_b",
    "column": 9,
    "line": 1,
    "line_source": "var a = 5",
    "name": "JSLintError",
    "message": "Expected ';' and instead saw '(end)'.",
    "formatted_message": " 1. \u001b[31mExpected ';' and instead saw '(end)'.\u001b[39m \u001b[90m// line 1, column 9\u001b[39m\n    var a = 5"
  }
]
```

I think the only change you'd make to your code is to lower-case `jslint`:

```
JSStringRef jsFunctionName = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("jslint");
```

---

#### Improvements?

Note that it's probably "even righter" to use `jslint_export`, which is a frozen copy of `jslint`.

```
JSStringRef jsFunctionName = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("jslint_export");
```

If you really wanted to, you could replace the `jslint_export` variable with `JSLINT` and not change your JavaScriptCore code at all.

```
// let jslint_export;              // The jslint object to be exported.
let JSLINT;                        // The jslint object to be exported.

// lots of stuff skipped

// jslint_export = Object.freeze(Object.assign(jslint, {
JSLINT = Object.freeze(Object.assign(jslint, {
    cli: Object.freeze(jslint_cli),
    edition: jslint_edition,
    jslint: Object.freeze(jslint.bind(undefined))
}));
```

I'd have to double-check the old code to see if this acts the same, but note that the actual linting function would be on `JSLINT.jslint` in that construction.

I'm not sure why there's so much global scope pollution in the current version of JSLint, however. Why this doesn't all live in an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) is confusing; I think it used to? Anyhow, this should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

instructions to import jslint as es-module is [here](https://github.com/jslint-org/jslint#3-to-import-jslintmjs-as-es-module).

```js
/*jslint devel*/
import jslint from "./jslint.mjs";
let code = "console.log('hello world');\n";
let result = jslint(code);
result.warnings.forEach(function ({
    formatted_message
}) {
    console.error(formatted_message);
});

// stderr
// 1 Undeclared 'console'. // line 1, column 1
// console.log('hello world');
// 2 Use double quotes, not single quotes. // line 1, column 13
// console.log('hello world');
```